# Свойство hover в нутри команды style. возможно ли?

Tags: html, css

Доброго всем времени суток господа. Второй раз за сегодня.

```
//style.css
//.superclass {background-color:#666666;}
//.superclass:hover {background-color:#999999;}

// используем на странице так:
<tr class="superclass">
```

Захотелось стиль сделать в место класса:

```
<tr style="background-color:#666666;">
```

Сразу не понятно как туда вписать :hover. Понятное дело, что через style.css и классы удобнее. Но все же возможно сделать свойство :hover внутри style?

p.s. Интересует хоть какой ни будь метод. В крайнем случае JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если js, то: [Решение, найденное поиском в гугле](http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=41425ce9778ba995&pli=1)

```
.s {
    color: red;
}
.s:hover {
    color: green;
}​
<div class="s">123</div>
<div style="color:red;" onmouseover="this.style.color = 'green';" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'red';">123</div>​
```

Дает одно и тоже

Comment: По ссылке, кстати, объяснено почему в style запихать не получится

Comment: жаль. думал все же как то можно. спасибо за решение.